# JRE 1.7+ required

Tags: java, exception, jnlp, ria

I have installed an update of a RIA application which is developed by a third party company. Now I get an error when I want to start, that JRE 1.7+ is required. The clients computer have JRE 1.6, but there are some cases where the application runs with JRE 1.6 and some other cases where it does not work with JRE 1.7.

Here is the exception i get:

```
JNLPException[category: Systemkonfiguration : Exception: null : LaunchDesc: 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/pro/Xpertline/xrec_ria/" href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/pro/Xpertline/xrec_ria/14BE3B0C80AC137A.jws.jnlp;jsessionid=11B1BB46F3B41F9ACABBEEFF0E9C1157">
  <information>
    <title>Axon.ivy Rich Internet Application</title>
    <vendor>ivyTeam AG</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.xpertline.ch"/>
    <description>Axon.ivy Rich Internet Application</description>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java initial-heap-size="33554432" max-heap-size="268435456" version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/commons-lang-2.5-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/de-javasoft-synthetica-netbeans-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/DJNativeSwing-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/DJNativeSwing-SWT-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/icepdf-core-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/icepdf-viewer-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ivyUlcExtension-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ivyUlcPatch-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jakarta-oro-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jcommon-client-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jfreechart-client-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jgoodies-looks-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jgoodies-plastic-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jydocking-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jytable-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jywidgets-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/lookuptextfield-extension-client-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/look_and_feel-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/MultipleGradientPaint-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/SteelSeries-3.9.23-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/swing-layout-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/swing-worker-1.1-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/swingx-1.6.5-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/synthetica-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddonsWithThemes-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAluOxide-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAluOxideAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBatik-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackEye-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackEyeAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackMoon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackMoonAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackStar-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackStarAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueIce-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueIceAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueLight-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueLightAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueMoon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueMoonAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueSteel-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueSteelAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaClassy-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaClassyAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaGreenDream-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaGreenDreamAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaMauveMetallic-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaMauveMetallicAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaOrangeMetallic-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaOrangeMetallicAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSilverMoon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSilverMoonAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSimple2D-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSimple2DAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSkyMetallic-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSkyMetallicAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaStandardAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaWhiteVision-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaWhiteVisionAddon-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/trident-6.3-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulc-applet-client-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulc-base-client-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulc-base-trusted-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulc-jnlp-client-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulc-servlet-client-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulcswingx-extension-client-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/vBamWidgets-client-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/xpertLineStandardLookAndFeel-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna_WindowUtils-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna_WindowUtils-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/swt-windows-32-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/swt-windows-32-5.1.20.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="ch.ivyteam.ivy.richdialog.client.RichApplicationLauncher">
    <argument>url-string=http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rd/Xpertline/xrec_ria</argument>
    <argument>http-session-id=11B1BB46F3B41F9ACABBEEFF0E9C1157</argument>
    <argument>init=14BE3B0C80AC137A</argument>
    <argument>look-and-feel=ch.xpertline.plaf.XpertLineStandardLookAndFeel</argument>
    <argument>client-coder-registry-provider=ch.ivyteam.ivy.ulc.client.coders.IvyClientCoderRegistryProvider</argument>
    <argument>connector-command-failure-strategy-provider=ch.ivyteam.ivy.richdialog.client.ConnectionFailureStrategyProvider</argument>
    <argument>log-level=WARNING</argument>
    <argument>keep-alive-interval=900</argument>
    <argument>show-splash-screen=true</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-bg-color=102,102,102</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-fg-color=255,255,255</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-border-width=1</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-msg=Please wait...</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-progress=-1</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-max-show=90</argument>
    <argument>client-operating-system-64-bit-show-warning=false</argument>
    <argument>client-operating-system-64-bit-warn-title=64 bit client detected</argument>
    <argument>client-operating-system-64-bit-warn-message=You are running this application on a 64-bit client. Some parts of the application may not behave as expected. 
We recommend to use a 32-bit browser to start the application.</argument>
    <argument>tool-tip-initial-delay=750</argument>
    <argument>tool-tip-dismiss-delay=16000</argument>
    <argument>tool-tip-reshow-delay=500</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp> ]
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.downloadJREResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and here is the jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/pro/Xpertline/xrec_ria" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/pro/Xpertline/xrec_ria/14BE3B47C1D5524E.jws.jnlp;jsessionid=11B1BB46F3B41F9ACABBEEFF0E9C1157">
  <information>
    <title>Axon.ivy Rich Internet Application</title>
    <vendor>ivyTeam AG</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.xpertline.ch"/>
    <description>Axon.ivy Rich Internet Application</description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" initial-heap-size="32m" max-heap-size="256m" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/commons-lang-2.5-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/de-javasoft-synthetica-netbeans-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/DJNativeSwing-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/DJNativeSwing-SWT-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/icepdf-core-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/icepdf-viewer-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ivyUlcExtension-5.1.20.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ivyUlcPatch-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jakarta-oro-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jcommon-client-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jfreechart-client-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jgoodies-looks-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jgoodies-plastic-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jydocking-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jytable-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/jywidgets-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/lookuptextfield-extension-client-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/look_and_feel-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/MultipleGradientPaint-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/SteelSeries-3.9.23-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/swing-layout-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/swing-worker-1.1-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/swingx-1.6.5-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/synthetica-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddonsWithThemes-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAluOxide-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAluOxideAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBatik-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackEye-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackEyeAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackMoon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackMoonAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackStar-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlackStarAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueIce-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueIceAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueLight-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueLightAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueMoon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueMoonAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueSteel-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaBlueSteelAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaClassy-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaClassyAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaGreenDream-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaGreenDreamAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaMauveMetallic-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaMauveMetallicAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaOrangeMetallic-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaOrangeMetallicAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSilverMoon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSilverMoonAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSimple2D-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSimple2DAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSkyMetallic-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaSkyMetallicAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaStandardAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaWhiteVision-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaWhiteVisionAddon-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/trident-6.3-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulc-applet-client-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulc-base-client-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulc-base-trusted-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulc-jnlp-client-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulc-servlet-client-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/ulcswingx-extension-client-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/vBamWidgets-client-5.1.20.jar" />
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/xpertLineStandardLookAndFeel-5.1.20.jar" />
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna_WindowUtils-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna_WindowUtils-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/swt-windows-32-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/swt-windows-32-5.1.20.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="i386">
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna_WindowUtils-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/jna_WindowUtils-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/swt-windows-32-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_native/swt-windows-32-5.1.20.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/jna_WindowUtils-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/jna_WindowUtils-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/swt-windows-64-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/swt-windows-64-5.1.20.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/jna_WindowUtils-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/jna_WindowUtils-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/swt-windows-64-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/windows_64_native/swt-windows-64-5.1.20.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_native/swt-linux-32-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_native/swt-linux-32-5.1.20.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux" arch="i386">
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_native/swt-linux-32-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_native/swt-linux-32-5.1.20.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64">
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_64_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_64_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_64_native/swt-linux-64-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_64_native/swt-linux-64-5.1.20.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Linux" arch="amd64">
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_64_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_64_native/jna-4.0.0-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_64_native/swt-linux-64-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/linux_64_native/swt-linux-64-5.1.20.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Mac" arch="i386">
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" />
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/mac_native/swt-mac-32-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/mac_native/swt-mac-32-5.1.20.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Mac" arch="x86_64">
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" />
    <nativelib href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/mac_64_native/swt-mac-64-5.1.20.jar"/>
    <jar href="http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rdlib/mac_64_native/swt-mac-64-5.1.20.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
<application-desc main-class="ch.ivyteam.ivy.richdialog.client.RichApplicationLauncher">
    <argument>url-string=http://xpiwingda31/ivy/rd/Xpertline/xrec_ria</argument>
    <argument>http-session-id=11B1BB46F3B41F9ACABBEEFF0E9C1157</argument>
    <argument>init=14BE3B47C1D5524E</argument>
    <argument>look-and-feel=ch.xpertline.plaf.XpertLineStandardLookAndFeel</argument>
    <argument>client-coder-registry-provider=ch.ivyteam.ivy.ulc.client.coders.IvyClientCoderRegistryProvider</argument>
    <argument>connector-command-failure-strategy-provider=ch.ivyteam.ivy.richdialog.client.ConnectionFailureStrategyProvider</argument>
    <argument>log-level=WARNING</argument>
    <argument>keep-alive-interval=900</argument>
    <argument>show-splash-screen=true</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-bg-color=102,102,102</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-fg-color=255,255,255</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-border-width=1</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-msg=Please wait...</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-progress=-1</argument>
    <argument>splash-screen-max-show=90</argument>
    <argument>client-operating-system-64-bit-show-warning=false</argument>
    <argument>client-operating-system-64-bit-warn-title=64 bit client detected</argument>
    <argument>client-operating-system-64-bit-warn-message=You are running this application on a 64-bit client. Some parts of the application may not behave as expected. 
We recommend to use a 32-bit browser to start the application.</argument>
    <argument>tool-tip-initial-delay=750</argument>
    <argument>tool-tip-dismiss-delay=16000</argument>
    <argument>tool-tip-reshow-delay=500</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

does anyboda have any idea what the problem might be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to remove that requirement from the JNLP file? (If you do that, and it actually does require JRE 1.7+, then it will probably crash anyway)

Comment: Contact the party who developed the application.

Comment: @Kayaman is right, maybe they have a configuration file for that..

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no influence to the contents of the jnlp. Oficcially it requires java 1.7 but it works on java 1.6. I have tested it on 1.6. But somehow it cannot be started even with java 1.7 installed. I do not know if it is a java problem or a probelm with other local installations.

the delevoping company is informed, but they won't come up with a solution fast, so I try to get a solution myself asap. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The client and I have now found a version of Java with which the application can be started on devices it did not work previously: JRE 1.7u67.

But i think this is a very specific solution.
However, thank you for your inputs!